# Debugging Camel Headers

Tags: apache-camel

I need to work on some Camel routes which contain lot of CBR based on the headers:

```
<simple>${header.CamelFileName} regex '^.*xml$'</simple>
```

It would be very helpful to debug the content of the Headers of the Routes: do you recommend any component/processor ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the DSL Log : http://camel.apache.org/logeip.html which is more confortable and comprehensible to use instead of a Log component (http://camel.apache.org/log.html) to debug headers.

```
<log message="CamelFileName : ${header.CamelFileName}; you can use simple langage" loggingLevel="FATAL" logName="com.mycompany.MyCoolRoute"/>
```

From the doc :

**Difference between log in the DSL and [Log] component**

> The log DSL is
>   much lighter and meant for logging human logs such as Starting to do
>   ... etc. It can only log a message based on the Simple language. On
>   the other hand Log component is a full fledged component which
>   involves using endpoints and etc. The Log component is meant for
>   logging the Message itself and you have many URI options to control
>   what you would like to be logged.

Hope

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Log** component for that task (http://camel.apache.org/log.html)

```
<to uri="log:like-to-see-all?level=INFO&amp;showAll=true&amp;multiline=true"/>
```

This code will help you to see all message headers

Comment: Thanks for your help!